# Java RMI server and Objective C client

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, servlets, rmi

I have a java rmi server and an objective C client. I want to use RMI to HTTP tunneling in order to encapsulate the RMI calls into HTTP requests where an RMI servlet handler can forward the call into the corresponding rmi server.

However I'm facing an issue. Let's say for instance that I created the stub and bound the stub on the registry with a certain name (on the server side).

Now in objective C, how can I locate the registry and lookup the stub? because in normal cases where we have an rmi client, it can be done this way:

Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("HelloServer");
and these are not remote procedure calls that I can send in http requests for the server to handle them.

So how can I "locate" the server remote object in an objective C client?

Any help is appreciated and if you need more information please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. RMI/JRMP requires a JVM. RMI/IIOP requires a JVM at the server and an ORB at the client (JVM contains an ORB for the server). IDL requires an ORB at the client as well, and you have to use the fully detailed CORBA API.